# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'bcrypt'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-import, bcrypt

**Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'bcrypt'**

I get the above error when I import bcrypt in my python code on AWS Lambda

My Python version is 3.8 and I've added python bcrypt 3.2.0 as a layer to my lambda function. There tutorial I referred to add Layers to Lambda is [here](https://medium.com/the-cloud-architect/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d)

The file structure for my bcrypt layer is
./python/bcryptfiles  (bcryptfiles is my bcrypt package)

I initially included the bcrypt package as a folder adjecent to my lambda_function.py file, which solved bcrypt import issue. But when I invoked checkpw, I got the error
**module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'checkpw'**

Can someone please suggest a solution? I couldn't find questions related to python bcrypt in AWS Lambda, hence raise this issue.

Source of my python bcrypt package download [here](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/#files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this bcrypt should be a library installed as a layer, you shouldn't need to add it adjacent to your lambda_handler.py file.

Also, you would probably need an amazon linux build (amazon linux 2 for python 3.8) to run it on this runtime.

One method that has helped me build unavailable packages in the past was this:
https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

Comment: Thank you for the response. I resolved the issue in a similar manner.